# Is there any attribute for the button to make it look stylish?

Tags: android

I am using the following. I want to add stylish properties like color and style.
   Please help

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
    android:text="OK" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste the following code into new xml file in drawable folder and name the file draw and

and in button give background of this xml file name

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="rectangle" >


    <solid android:color="#1F2120" />
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="6dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="6dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:topLeftRadius="6dp"
        android:topRightRadius="6dp" />

</shape>
```

this is how you can use this

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/force"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/draw"
    android:text="some txt"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="20dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add images to this button by using :

```
android:background="@drawable/image_name"
```

if you want to simply add some color to this button's background, you can do it like this:

```
android:background="#ff0000"  // color code for red color
```

besides, you can specify text color like this :

```
android:textColor="#0000ff"   // color code for blue color
```

if you want to change your button's background on different events like while the button is foccused, pressed etc. you need to create an xml file say `mybutton_style.xml` in`drawable` folder.

```
// code for mybutton_style.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_pressed="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/btn_image_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
     <item android:state_focused="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/btn_image_focussed" /> <!--focused -->
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_image_default" /> <!-- default -->
 </selector>
```

after that you just need to specify it as your button's background:

```
android:background="@drawable/mybutton_style"
```

Answer (score 0):

**copy** following bg.xml file  in  to your `drawable` folder.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <item android:state_pressed="true"><shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners android:radius="10dp" />
    <gradient
                    android:endColor="#fffffa"
                    android:startColor="#ffffff"
                    android:angle="270" />
                <solid android:color="#00aa00" />

                <padding android:bottom="10.0dip" android:left="10.0dip" android:right="10.0dip" android:top="10.0dip" />


            </shape></item>
        <item android:state_pressed="false"><shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners android:radius="10dp" />

                <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <gradient
                    android:endColor="#fffffa"
                    android:startColor="#ffffff"
                    android:angle="270" />
                <padding android:bottom="10.0dip" android:left="10.0dip" android:right="10.0dip" android:top="10.0dip" />


            </shape></item>

    </selector>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
 android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
    android:text="OK" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Custom Style for bottom displaying confirm and cancel -->
<style name="Widget.GsMenuButton" parent="@style/Widget.Button"> 
    <item name="android:layout_height">36px</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">82px</item>
            <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
            <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
    <item name="background">@drawable/gs_menu_btn</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
</style>
```

This is what i have done to make my button. It change the button background color with background attribute and change the text color with `android:textColor`. I think you can just add these to your button attribute.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make your button stylish but in simple way then you can try the following:

```
android:background="@null"
android:typeface="serif"
```

if you don't want simple stuff then you can customize it as you want.

Comment: Are you trying to troll?